# Typescript AMD implementation bad with Javascript / RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, typescript

If I have this ts module:

```
export function say(){
    console.log("said");
}
```

and I compile it with the amd option I can use it quite easily from a ts client :

```
import foo = module("tsmodule")
foo.say();

export var x = 123;
```

However if I have javascript equivalent to the ts module:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    function say() {
        console.log("said");
    }
    exports.say = say;
})
```

There is no way to use it easily. The simplest possible solution:

```
// of course you can use .d.ts for requirejs but that is beside the point
declare var require:any;

// will fail with error module has not been loaded yet for context
// http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
var useme = require("jsmodule")
useme.say();

export var x = 123;
import foo = module("tsmodule")
foo.say();
```

fails because of error http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded . Since "jsmodule" was not passed to the define call in the generated typescript.

The two workarounds I have

- don't use import / export (language features lost)
- use require([]) (still can't export something that depends on the require([]) call)

have limitations : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-requirejs . Is there another way? If not can you vote here : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/948 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to load in a JavaScript module you could always use the (badly documented) `amd-dependency` tag:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="jsmodule" />
```

This will put `jsmodule` in the dependency array of your define call.

And then provide a declaration file in which you would simply state

```
module useme {
    function say(): void;
}
```

Comment: apparently an undocumented feature, and does not work with my tsc version 0.9.0 alpha. Let me uninstall / install to version 0.8

Comment: Aww shoot, they removed this in 0.9?! I'm using 0.8.1.1.

Comment: Works in 0.8.3 . But not in 0.9.0alpha

Comment: Good to know. I hope they include similar functionality in 0.9+ as I rely heavily on this feature

Comment: 0.9a is supposed to have a few utility bits missing. Hopefully `amd-dependency` is one of these. I do hope they haven't removed it permanently.